# How to install nodejs in cpanel shared hosting(linux based)

Tags: node.js, linux, cpanel

I created chatting application in nodejs and want to  run nodejs server on cpanel linux based hosting. Someone please guide me, or give me step wise instructions to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with shared hosting. Unless they explicitly mention they support it.

Comment: i tried installing composer using git bash. but after that i dont know how to install npm and further .

Comment: try a vps provider like digitalocean or linode. they start at 5$ per month which is very reasonable IMO